# Lucene - Get docId or document by using the docValue

Tags: lucene

Say the *docValue* of a particular field is known. Is it possible to get the list of *docId* that match the *docValue* from the index?

I'm using Lucene 4.6.0.

Comment: @groverboy Sorry it's DocValues aka. Column Stride Fields. [DocValues](http://www.lucenerevolution.org/sites/default/files/Willnauer%20Simon%20-%20DocValues%20Column%20Stride%20Fields%20in%20Lucene.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by doing a sequential search (on disk or memory) over the DocValues. This is similar to the values in a FieldCache but the implementation is different.

In **Lucene 4.6** you have to look at specific implementations of `FunctionValue`: http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queries/org/apache/lucene/queries/function/FunctionValues.html

In **Lucene 4.0** the API was like this:
The DocValues.getDirectSource() returns the source which you can use for disk-based access. DocValues.getSource() for the memory-based access. The Source class and the specific subclasses provide methods to access the values.

Comment: Could you point me towards the link that contains the JavaDocs for getEnum(). I'm unbale to find it in the JavaDocs for Lucene 4.6.0

Comment: sorry, the api changed. I adapted my response.

Comment: Pardon me but I'm still unable to find the JavaDocs for the class DocValues. Could you please post the link. A google search throws a result for Lucene 4.1.0. I'm using Lucene 4.6.0.

Comment: sorry me...a lot of api changes happened around doc values. I added the actual reference to my answer.

Comment: Looks like sequential search may be the only option. Is it possible to use a filter over DocValues and perform a search?

Comment: Yes it is. You can implement a filter which returns a DocIdSet and in its iterator, you can iterate over the DocValues and decide whether it's a match or not.